# Can I connect ActivePivot to the tableau software?

Tags: tableau-api, activepivot

I would like to know if it is possible to connect activepivot to tableau software ?
By the way is it possible to connect to microsoft reporting services ?

Answer (score 1):

Based the information I see here:

http://quartetfs.com/en/products/activepivot/open-component

...the product understands MDX. It also allows connectivity from Excel, which infers that there is an ODBC / Other driver that Tableau could also probably leverage.

So, I suspect the answer is "yes", but you'll need to tell us a little bit more about connectivity options for ActivePivot before you can be sure.

Answer (score 0):

ActivePivot implements the standards of OLAP:

- The MDX query language
- The XMLA protocol for communications

So does Tableau Software.

When a multidimensional (MDX) query is sent to an OLAP provider like ActivePivot, a cell set is returned, encoded in the XMLA protocol. Most OLAP frontends (Microsoft Excel in particular) rely on a "multidimensional format" to represent the cell set in XMLA. But a few rely on the older "tabular format", that is the case of Tableau Software (and also Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services).

ActivePivot supports the XMLA multidimensional format since version 2.0 and the tabular format since version 4.3.3. ActivePivot 4.3.3 has been tested and works with Tableau Software.